# Drawing grids using loops in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw the diagram below[image: BOND].

One way is to do this by using tikzpicture and drawing each point on the grid separately. Which, of course, is very time-consuming.

Is there any way this grid can be drawn by a `for` loop along with the partial labeling of the grid point, just like the diagram?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The grid can be drawn without a loop using `grid` with `line width=2pt, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 1cm`. The individual points can be labeled and numbered as `coordinate`s using a loop. Then `\draw` the lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=2pt, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 1cm](0,0) grid (5,5);
\foreach \n in {1,...,16} {\coordinate[label=135:\n](\n) at({1+mod(\n-1,4)},{4-div(\n-1,4)});}
\draw (1)--(2)--(6)--(5)--(1) (3)--(4)--(8)--(7)--(3) (11)--(10)--(14);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `cycle`: `\draw (1)--(2)--(6)--(5)--cycle (3)--(4)--(8)--(7)--cycle (11)--(10)--(14);`.